# XSLT one to many mapping?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am invoking a web service which gives back an xml as response. The structure of this xml response is

```
<xsd:complexType name="MoveToNextSecretQuestionResponseType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="question" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="authSessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="questionId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="answerList" type="answerList"/>
    <xsd:element name="locale" type="LocaleType"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

My scenario is I need to store this response to another variable say **Response** of the structure

```
<xsd:element name="questionResponse"
               type="MoveToNextSecretQuestionResponseType"
               maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

Here I am trying to get something like this using my xsl where iterator, request and response are respective inputs/output and this xsl is placed inside while loop.

```
while(iterator>=0){
call the web service.
store the response into source variable.
call the xsl(source=Response[iterator])
iterator= iterator-1
```

}
send Response variable back with

```
<questionResponse>
<MoveToNextSecretQuestionResponseType></MoveToNextSecretQuestionResponseType>
<MoveToNextSecretQuestionResponseType></MoveToNextSecretQuestionResponseType>
<MoveToNextSecretQuestionResponseType></MoveToNextSecretQuestionResponseType>
 .
 .
 .
</questionResponse>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What language is your "while" loop written in? Why aren't you doing the whole thing in XSLT?

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for your reply, I am using BPEL(oracle SOA) to implement this logic. The code which I have mentioned there is a generalized one just to understand the flow.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know BPEL.